# How to animate background opacity without affecting content opacity (when hover)?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

in the beginning i've made some `<a>` buttons, and wrote a:hover rule with regular css that just puts an underline on the link when hover.

Now, i wanna take it to the next level and animate it to change just the opacity of the background..
thanks very much!

*for example the `<a>`element:
`<a href="#contact">Contact</a>`

*now the css hover rule:
`a:hover{
    background-color: rgba(71,117,255,0.5);
}`

i just took the same color and gave it 0.5 opacity with rgba.
now i want the same thing just animate it with JQuery.

Comment: What do your current a and a:hover class look like? What background color do your links have currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the button just has a single `background-color`, you can use `rgba` to change the color opacity without affecting other properties. Sample:

```
button {
    background-color: #f000;
    color: #333;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Pay attention to `transition` timing and easing function for adjusting it to your own needs. Also, remember to add a `-webkit-transition` prefixed version if you care about Androids before 4.4 (as shown by http://caniuse.com/#search=transition).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you used `:hover` in CSS. You just keep expanding on that

Sample Code:

HTML

```
<button type='button' class='sampleBtn'>Hover Here</button>
```

CSS

```
.sampleBtn
{
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
.sampleBtn:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    opacity: 0.4;
    border: none;
}
```

A working example: https://jsfiddle.net/oz9hw2Lt/1/